# Ruby oneliner for defining, iterating over array, adding and returning value?

Tags: ruby

I have this piece of code:

```
def total_balance
  total = 0
  users.each { |user| total += user.balance }
  total
end
```

and i wonder if there is a shorter version/one liner for this?

it basically iterates over users and adds their balance together.

ty!

Comment: If `users` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `balance` is just a database-mapped field (with no transformations on top of raw data), then this job is better to be delegated to the database: `users.sum(:balance)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
def total_balance
  users.sum { |user| user.balance }
  # or users.sum(&:balance)
  # or users.map(&:balance).sum
  # or users.reduce(0) { |total, user| total += user.balance }
  # or users.inject(0) { |total, user| total += user.balance }
end
```

With the `inject` or `reduce`, I always get the accumulator and the object mixed up in the pipe variables. But that's easy to fix with debugging :D

Comment: `users.sum(&:balance)`

Comment: "With the inject or reduce, I always get the accumulator and the object mixed up" - a mnemonic I use is "reduce does the opposite of `each_with_object`" (which passes the element first and accumulator after, "each, object").